# Why is my code printing out letter by letter instead of sentence by sentence?

Tags: c

The aim of my code is to read in multiple lines of text from a text file and for each line, print out "palindrome" then the line of text if it's a palindrome and print out "Not palindrome" and the line of text if it's not palindrome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int palindrome(char str[])
{
   int l=0;
   int h = strlen(str) -1;
    while (h>l)
        {
           if (str[l++] != str[h--])
              {
                printf("%s -> Not Palindrome",str);
                return;
              }
 }
printf("%s is palindrome",str);
}
   int main()
 {
    char str[100];
    FILE*fptr;
    fptr= fopen("Lab12input.txt","r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
       {
        printf("can't open file");
        exit(0);
       }
    while (fscanf(fptr,"%s",str) != EOF)
      {
        palindrome(str);
        printf("\n");
      }
   fclose(fptr);
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Post example  data from `"Lab12input.txt"`.

Comment: I suspect the .txt file may be save as a UTF-16 one.   (That explains the "printing out letter by letter") What is the size  of the file?  What is its character count?

Comment: Nit - `printf("\n");` -> `putchar ('\n');` No need to use the variadic `printf` to output a single-character -- that's what `putchar()` is for. (even though a smart compiler should make the replacement for you). Further, your `int palindrome()` function fails to return a value. Perhaps `return 0;` on failure, `return 1;` on success? (your compiler should be warning you of that fact)

Comment: Example:  Go hang a salami, I'm a lasagna hog!

Answer (score 1):

uhh a `%s` to `[fs]?scanf()` is a whitespace-delimited word, it breaks at the space character. By "sentence by sentence" you mean "line by line" which is what `fgets()` does.

Comment: That is actually quite correct, but I would encourage you to start your answers with something other than `"uhh"` (though I get that was intended in somewhat of a bit of subtle humor) Also worth a mention of POSIX `getline` (the other *line-oriented* input function) Final nit `"breaks at the space character"` -> `"breaks at any whitespace character"` `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin well `getline` is off in its own package, library, and header isn't it, and isn't present (or exists but with wildly different semantics) on BSD, Sun, or System V Unices older than 10 years.Also success tends to be 0 and failure tends to be all other values, if returning any size of int.

Comment: Yes, `getline` is a POSIX function -- and most compilers provide it. Since it is POSIX, it's functionality will be the same, but all compilers will provide there own implementation. It has pretty much been the same `getline` for at least two decades.